# How do I edit the head and body of a page in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, html, design

I've developed a custom HTML menu that I'd love to deploy to SharePoint. The two working files are:

**Index**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Intranet</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Intranet Testing">        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/a_main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header-container">
            <h1>Testing Environment</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="main-container">
        <div class="tileContainer"></div>

        </div> <!-- #main-container -->

        <div class="footer-container">
            <footer class="wrapper">
            </footer>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" content="application/javascript" src="js/tiles.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){
            $('.tileContainer').hide().fadeIn(1000);

            $('.tileContainer').tiles({
               'width'     : 150, // width of the tile
               'height'    : 100, // height of the tile
               'align'     : 'center', // align the text and icon either 'left' or 'center'. There is no right.
               'textColour': '#ffffff', // colour of the text
               'colour'    : '#2b92b1', // tile colour
               'rolloverColour' : '#a2d614', // colour of the bottom border
               'clickColour'    : '#a2d614', // colour the tile turns when the user clicks the tile
               'columns'   : 0, // how many tiles are set till it starts a new row
               'iconsPath' : 'img/tiles/', // path to where all the icons are on the server. It needs the slash on the end.
               'effect'    : 'fadeIn', // Doesn't really do anything yet... I'll get to it.
               'tile'      : [{
                        'label' : 'Square 01 tile', // Text label
                        'link'  : 'google.com', // Link to apply to tile (optional)
                        'icon'  : 'windows.png' // Icon to use (optional)
                        },{
                        'label' : 'Square 02',
                        'link'  : '',
                        'icon'  : ''
                        },{
                        'label' : 'Square 03',
                        'link'  : 'reddit.com',
                        'icon'  : ''
                        },{
                        'label' : 'Square 04',
                        'link'  : '',
                        'icon'  : ''
                        }
                        ,{
                        'label' : 'Square 05',
                        'link'  : '',
                        'icon'  : ''
                        }
               ]
           });

        });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Tiles.js**

```
// TILES JS v1.0 //


jQuery.fn.extend({
    tiles: function(args, callback){

        var tileArray = args['tile'];
        var iconFolder = args['iconsPath'];
        var parentElement = $(this);
        var columns = args['columns'];
        var columnCount = 0;

        parentElement.html('<ul class="tileList"></ul>');

        $.each(tileArray, function(key, value){
            var icon = "";
            if(tileArray[key]['icon'].length >= 1){
                icon = '<img class="tileIcon" src="'+iconFolder+tileArray[key]['icon']+'" />';
            }
            parentElement.children('.tileList').append('<li class="tile">'+icon+'<p class="tileText">'+tileArray[key]['label']+'</p></li>');

            var link = "";
            if(tileArray[key]['link'].length >= 1){
                link = '<a class="tileLink" href="'+tileArray[key]['link']+'"></a>';
                parentElement.find('.tile').last().wrapInner(link);
            }

            var align = "";
            if(args['align'] == 'center'){
                parentElement.find('.tile').last().find('.tileText').addClass('tileTextCenter');
                parentElement.find('.tile').last().find('.tileIcon').addClass('tileIconCenter');
            }

            columnCount++;

            if(columnCount === columns){
                parentElement.children('.tileList').append('<br clear="all" />');
                columnCount = 0;
            };



        });

        parentElement.children('.tileList').append('<br clear="all" />');
        $('head').append('<style>.tileList .tile {-webkit-transition: border-bottom 100ms ease-out, height 100ms ease-out;-moz-transition: border-bottom 100ms ease-out, height 100ms ease-out;-o-transition: border-bottom 100ms ease-out, height 100ms ease-out;transition: border-bottom 100ms ease-out, height 100ms ease-out;width: 100px;height: 100px;overflow: hidden;background-color: rgb(77,144,215);position: relative;color: rgb(255,255,255);border-bottom: 0px solid rgb(6, 182, 219);float: left;margin: 0 2px 2px 0;display: block;}.tileList .tileText {position: absolute;margin: 0;bottom: 0px;text-align: left;padding: 5px;line-height: 1em;color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;}.tileList .tileText.tileTextCenter {position: absolute;display: block;width: 90%;text-align: center;padding: 5px 5%;}.tileIconCenter{margin: 0 auto;display: block;}.lt-ie9 .tileList .tileText {position: absolute;margin: 20px;bottom: 0px;text-align: left;padding: 5px;line-height: 1em;}.tileList .tile:hover {-webkit-transition: border-bottom 100ms ease-out, height 100ms ease-out;-moz-transition: border-bottom 100ms ease-out, height 100ms ease-out;-o-transition: border-bottom 100ms ease-out, height 100ms ease-out;transition: border-bottom 100ms ease-out, height 100ms ease-out;border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(6, 182, 219);height:90px;cursor: pointer;}.tileList .tile:active, .tileList .tileIcon:active{background-color: rgb(6, 182, 219);cursor: pointer;}.ie .tileList .tileText:active {background-color: rgb(6, 182, 219);} /*////////////////////////*/ .tileList .tile{ width:'+args['width']+'px; height:'+args['height']+'px; background-color:'+args['colour']+';}  .tileLink { display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; } .tileList .tile:hover{ height: '+(args['height']-10)+'px; border-bottom: 10px solid '+args['rolloverColour']+';}</style>');

        callback = 'hi';
        return callback;
    }
})
```

I've opened my homepage in SharePoint designer and I'm trying to work out how to migrate what I've created in the HTML above, into the SharePoint page - but the format is totally different. There are no head tags, no body tags - I'm lost! Is this even possible to deploy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The header and footer (the chrome) of SharePoint and most Asp.Net websites is defined in a master page. For SharePoint 2013 this is by default the seattle.master.

My tip is to create your own master page by taking a copy of the Seattle.master, or using a Delegate control to insert your control.

Create SharePoint master page :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205273.aspx

Delegate controls:
http://www.fivenumber.com/understanding-sharepoint-delegate-control/

There are more information regarding both approaches both here and scattered over the web.

A not so smooth solution could otherwise be to use JavaScript to move your menu to the correct place in the DOM